# How to extract this text from this Website Scraping? BeatifulSoup

Tags: python

I'm trying to extract the string "No disponble" of this product, but im getting "none" or attribute text dont exists:

[image]

https://es.louisvuitton.com/esp-es/productos/neceser-26-monogram-canvas-000767#M47542

```
disponibilidad = soup.find("span", {"class":"lv-stock-indicator lv-product-stock-indicator lv- 
product__stock list-label-m -not-available"}).text
```

But im getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: It seems like the class is dynamically generated

Comment: Yes, it is. Browse with javascript off and the desired text does not appear. You'll need Selenium or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments content is dynamically generated but you can go with selenium.

**Example**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')

url = 'https://es.louisvuitton.com/esp-es/productos/neceser-26-monogram-canvas-000767#M47542'
driver.get(url)
sleep(2)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")

print(soup.select_one('div.lv-product__price-stock > span')).get_text()

driver.close()
```

**Output**

> No disponible

---

### Get in stock information without selenium

If you just interessted if product is available you can also `requests` the api with the `sku` of the product (hint and homework - last part of your url :)

**Example**

```
import requests, json
from time import sleep
headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}

skuList = ['M47542', 'M45587', '1A8EMO']
availabilities = {}

for id in idList:
    r=requests.get('https://api.louisvuitton.com/api/esp-es/catalog/availability/{0}'.format(id),headers=headers)
    availabilities[id] = (r.json()['skuAvailability'])
    print(r.json()['skuAvailability'])
    sleep(4)
```

**Output availabilities**

```
{'000767': [{'skuId': 'M47542',
   'exists': True,
   'backOrder': False,
   'inStock': False}],
 'nvprod2540049v': [{'skuId': 'M45587',
   'exists': True,
   'backOrder': False,
   'inStock': False},
  {'skuId': 'M45586', 'exists': True, 'backOrder': False, 'inStock': False}],
 'nvprod2470212v': [{'skuId': '1A8EMO',
   'exists': True,
   'backOrder': False,
   'inStock': False},
  {'skuId': '1A8EMQ', 'exists': True, 'backOrder': False, 'inStock': False},
  {'skuId': '1A8EMS', 'exists': True, 'backOrder': False, 'inStock': False},
  {'skuId': '1A8EMU', 'exists': True, 'backOrder': False, 'inStock': False},
  {'skuId': '1A8EMW', 'exists': True, 'backOrder': False, 'inStock': False},
  {'skuId': '1A8EMY', 'exists': True, 'backOrder': False, 'inStock': False},
  {'skuId': '1A8EN0', 'exists': True, 'backOrder': False, 'inStock': False},
  {'skuId': '1A8EM9', 'exists': True, 'backOrder': False, 'inStock': False},
  {'skuId': '1A8EMB', 'exists': True, 'backOrder': False, 'inStock': True},
  {'skuId': '1A8EMD', 'exists': True, 'backOrder': False, 'inStock': False},
  {'skuId': '1A8EMF', 'exists': True, 'backOrder': False, 'inStock': True},
  {'skuId': '1A8EMH', 'exists': True, 'backOrder': False, 'inStock': False},
  {'skuId': '1A8EMJ', 'exists': True, 'backOrder': False, 'inStock': False},
  {'skuId': '1A8EML', 'exists': True, 'backOrder': False, 'inStock': False}]}
```

Comment: Is not possible to extract without using Selenium?

Comment: Not that way you have asked, but there is an solution - Take a look at my edit, hope that is also fine for you.

Comment: For accessing the API you will be getting a CORS Error...